# Where do I write code when a form is loading?

Tags: c++, qt

In Visual Studio, to write code in `form_load` event, you must double-click in the form and then write the code.

I want to write the code in a loading form.

How and where must write it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no form loading event. In C++ Qt projects, you should write your initialization code in the constructor of your form.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e41J5.jpg)

Writing the code in the **red part** is the solution to the problem.

The first part of the program that runs is the same.